# Write d.ts for the react class component, but it cannot be compiled

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My original intention was to write a type declaration (.d.ts) for an old react class component, instead of refactoring the component using typescript.

Currently my declaration file is written like this:

```js
// src/typings/table.d.ts：

import React from 'react'
// other import

interface TableProps { 
  // ...
}

interface TableState {
  // ...
}

export default class Table extends React.Component<TableProps, TableState> {
  constructor(props: TableConfig): void

  rowIndex: number
  renderData: Row[]
  // ...

  marquee(): void
  scrollTo(rowIndex: number, targetScrollTop: number): void
  // ...
}
```

I export Table declaration in tsx file:

```js
// src/table.tsx：

import util from '@/util'
import Table from '@/typings/table'

export default class extends Table {
  constructor(props: TableConfig) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      colWidth: [],
      scrollHeight: util.getScrollHeight(props),
      selected: {rowCheckbox: []},
      indeterminate: false,
      headerWidth: 0,
      transitionName: '',
      // other state
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {}
  componentDidUpdate() {}
  render() {}
  // other react life cycles

  this.rowIndex = 0
  this.renderData = util.fillRow(data, this.state)
  // Other custom attributes

  scrollList(rowIndex, targetScrollTop) {}
  marquee() {}
  // other custom methods
}
```

If I write like this, I will get a compilation error:

```
ERROR in ./src/table.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/typings/table' in 'D:\Projects\src'
 @ ./src/table.tsx 64:8-120
 @ ./src/index.tsx
 @ ./app/index.jsx
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I am not familiar with typescript. How can I export a type declaration for a react class component?

Comment: Why have the `.d.ts` file at all? If you're writing the actual component in TypeScript, you don't need it.

Comment: This component is a component written a long time ago. Many custom methods and attributes have been added to the class. The function is very complicated and the structure is a bit outdated. But for some reasons, I have to continue to use it, so I need to write a separate class. Constrain this class of components

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide some context? How does it lead to *"I need to write a separate class"* in a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: I have added a little context. I wonder if it is enough for you to understand my component and my intentions?